# Does changing the HTML 'lang' attribute after page load have any effect?

Tags: javascript, html, screen-readers, lang

I have a page that has no attributes defined in the HTML tag (`<html>`). I need to make the page W3C compliant and that requires the correct attribute structure, namely:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

Obviously editing this tag in source would be the solution, but I don't actually have access to that. I can easily use jQuery to add the attributes, but I'm unsure if they have any effect considering the page has already loaded by the time the jQuery script would run.

Does anyone know if changing the tag after the fact has the same effect for screen readers?

Answer (score 0):

Screen readers do have excellent support for javascript and they also wait for use document ready to complete to read the screen.

So my guess is that this should work, but this may deffer from reader to reader.

Now, if your question is not about readers, but its about crawlers (google, bing, yahoo and so on...) best guess is that this won't have any effect at all.

Now, as far as W3 compliance. feel free to know that this won't work in the w3 validator :)

Comment: Thank you. My only concern is if it will pass an accessibilty audit which is based on these guidelines: [https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H57.html](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H57.html) - I guess I need a screen-reader to see if it switches langauges. Mac's built in one just reads in English.

Comment: Oh i guess I can download other languages.